# cas client call service validate url /serviceValidate and got CAS server login page html,not xml result

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, shiro

i'm using shiro-cas client 1.2.3 in my webapp and cas server 4.2.0 as sso server,I found  my cas client got login page html content when call url /ucas/serviceValidate  validate service ticket,it seems /serviceValidate had been redirected to cas server login page.
i got these log form  server:

```
[INFO][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager]UcasAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated admin
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver]Attempting to resolve a principal...
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver]Creating SimplePrincipal for [admin]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver]Principal id [admin] could not be found
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver]Retrieved [4] attribute(s) from the repository
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager]org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver@11e7f88e resolved admin from admin
[INFO][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager]Authenticated admin with credentials [admin].
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager]Attribute map for admin: {uid=uid, eduPersonAffiliation=eduPersonAffiliation, memberOf=[faculty, staff, org], groupMembership=groupMembership}
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.TicketOrCredentialPrincipalResolver]Resolving argument [AuthenticationTransaction] for audit
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.TicketOrCredentialPrincipalResolver]Resolving argument [UsernamePasswordCredential] for audit
[INFO][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager]Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: admin
WHAT: Supplied credentials: [admin]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sat Apr 29 14:02:49 CST 2017
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationTransactionManager]Successful authentication; Collecting authentication result [org.jasig.cas.authentication.ImmutableAuthentication@ef8c9139]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationTransactionManager]Transaction ignored since there are no credentials to authenticate
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collecting authentication history based on [1] authentication events
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Evaluating authentication principal [admin] for inclusion in context
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collected principal attributes [{uid=uid, memberOf=[faculty, staff, org], groupMembership=groupMembership, eduPersonAffiliation=eduPersonAffiliation}] for inclusion in context for principal [admin]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collected single authentication attribute [authenticationMethod] -> [UcasAuthenticationHandler]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collected single authentication attribute [successfulAuthenticationHandlers] -> [[UcasAuthenticationHandler]]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Finalized authentication attributes [{authenticationMethod=UcasAuthenticationHandler, successfulAuthenticationHandlers=[UcasAuthenticationHandler]}] for inclusion in authentication context
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultPrincipalElectionStrategy]Nominated [admin] as the primary principal
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Determined primary authentication principal to be [admin]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collected authentication attributes for this context are [{authenticationMethod=UcasAuthenticationHandler, successfulAuthenticationHandlers=[UcasAuthenticationHandler]}]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Authentication context commenced at [2017-04-29T14:02:49.773+08:00]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Building an authentication context for authentication org.jasig.cas.authentication.ImmutableAuthentication@835b2f9 and service http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]Added ticket [TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost] to registry.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl]Publishing org.jasig.cas.support.events.CasTicketGrantingTicketCreatedEvent@200cbbb8[ticketGrantingTicket=TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.TicketOrCredentialPrincipalResolver]Resolving argument [DefaultAuthenticationContext] for audit
[INFO][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager]Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sat Apr 29 14:02:49 CST 2017
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.web.support.WebUtils]Evaluating request to determine if warning cookie should be generated
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.web.WarningCookieRetrievingCookieGenerator]Removed cookie with name [CASPRIVACY]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.SendTicketGrantingTicketAction]Setting TGC for current session.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultCasCookieValueManager]Encoding cookie value [TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1@Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.util.DefaultCipherExecutor]Encrypting via [A128CBC-HS256]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.PlaintextNoneAlgorithm@6c7c98cd registered for alg algorithm none
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.HmacUsingShaAlgorithm$HmacSha256@7c145051 registered for alg algorithm HS256
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.HmacUsingShaAlgorithm$HmacSha384@53065946 registered for alg algorithm HS384
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.HmacUsingShaAlgorithm$HmacSha512@76b1d1bc registered for alg algorithm HS512
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.EcdsaUsingShaAlgorithm$EcdsaP256UsingSha256@24f91458 registered for alg algorithm ES256
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.EcdsaUsingShaAlgorithm$EcdsaP384UsingSha384@3e4e71e0 registered for alg algorithm ES384
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.EcdsaUsingShaAlgorithm$EcdsaP521UsingSha512@305aeea0 registered for alg algorithm ES512
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.RsaUsingShaAlgorithm$RsaSha256@52085950 registered for alg algorithm RS256
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.RsaUsingShaAlgorithm$RsaSha384@4859575d registered for alg algorithm RS384
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jws.RsaUsingShaAlgorithm$RsaSha512@5788725d registered for alg algorithm RS512
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]PS256 is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]PS384 is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->JsonWebSignatureAlgorithm]PS512 is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.RsaKeyManagementAlgorithm$Rsa1_5@cdfd4c8 registered for alg algorithm RSA1_5
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.RsaKeyManagementAlgorithm$RsaOaep@194d93b6 registered for alg algorithm RSA-OAEP
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.RsaKeyManagementAlgorithm$RsaOaep256@7af5b7bb registered for alg algorithm RSA-OAEP-256
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.DirectKeyManagementAlgorithm@20800faf registered for alg algorithm dir
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.AesKeyWrapManagementAlgorithm$Aes128@1b44ad0 registered for alg algorithm A128KW
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]A192KW is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]A256KW is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.EcdhKeyAgreementAlgorithm@15bd9ee4 registered for alg algorithm ECDH-ES
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.EcdhKeyAgreementWithAesKeyWrapAlgorithm$EcdhKeyAgreementWithAes128KeyWrapAlgorithm@4c06729d registered for alg algorithm ECDH-ES+A128KW
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]ECDH-ES+A192KW is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]ECDH-ES+A256KW is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.Pbes2HmacShaWithAesKeyWrapAlgorithm$HmacSha256Aes128@395d8c76 registered for alg algorithm PBES2-HS256+A128KW
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]PBES2-HS384+A192KW is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]PBES2-HS512+A256KW is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.AesGcmKeyEncryptionAlgorithm$Aes128Gcm@3f84cdcf registered for alg algorithm A128GCMKW
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]A192GCMKW is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->KeyManagementAlgorithm]A256GCMKW is unavailable so will not be registered for alg algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.AesCbcHmacSha2ContentEncryptionAlgorithm$Aes128CbcHmacSha256@6354da9f registered for enc algorithm A128CBC-HS256
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm]A192CBC-HS384 is unavailable so will not be registered for enc algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm]A256CBC-HS512 is unavailable so will not be registered for enc algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm]org.jose4j.jwe.AesGcmContentEncryptionAlgorithm$Aes128Gcm@1d495668 registered for enc algorithm A128GCM
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm]A192GCM is unavailable so will not be registered for enc algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm]A256GCM is unavailable so will not be registered for enc algorithms.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][class org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactory->CompressionAlgorithm]org.jose4j.zip.DeflateRFC1951CompressionAlgorithm@3c82ae83 registered for zip algorithm DEF
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.web.support.TGCCookieRetrievingCookieGenerator]Added cookie with name [TGC] and value [eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.OeZ8ypOngQWnheTEoAeRNJSa7D4R6xGvNINzr2YQldo6WUXjFzKfUEon7TsH3e54V-qf7Pa0QSMENJnZmbYrcQ]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]Ticket [TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost] found in registry.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collecting authentication history based on [1] authentication events
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Evaluating authentication principal [admin] for inclusion in context
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collected principal attributes [{uid=uid, memberOf=[faculty, staff, org], groupMembership=groupMembership, eduPersonAffiliation=eduPersonAffiliation}] for inclusion in context for principal [admin]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collected single authentication attribute [authenticationMethod] -> [UcasAuthenticationHandler]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collected single authentication attribute [successfulAuthenticationHandlers] -> [[UcasAuthenticationHandler]]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Finalized authentication attributes [{authenticationMethod=UcasAuthenticationHandler, successfulAuthenticationHandlers=[UcasAuthenticationHandler]}] for inclusion in authentication context
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultPrincipalElectionStrategy]Nominated [admin] as the primary principal
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Determined primary authentication principal to be [admin]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Collected authentication attributes for this context are [{authenticationMethod=UcasAuthenticationHandler, successfulAuthenticationHandlers=[UcasAuthenticationHandler]}]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Authentication context commenced at [2017-04-29T14:02:49.898+08:00]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationContextBuilder]Building an authentication context for authentication org.jasig.cas.authentication.ImmutableAuthentication@efafdf4 and service http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]Ticket [TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost] found in registry.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.DefaultPrincipalAttributesRepository]DefaultPrincipalAttributesRepository will return the collection of attributes directly associated with the principal object
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.DefaultPrincipalAttributesRepository]Found [4] cached attributes for principal [admin]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy]No required attributes are specified
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.ticket.DefaultServiceTicketFactory]Looking up service ticket id generator for [org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.SimpleWebApplicationServiceImpl]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]Added ticket [ST-1-TI2dqfpSJIm9BTQs0tZE-localhost] to registry.
[INFO][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl]Granted ticket [ST-1-TI2dqfpSJIm9BTQs0tZE-localhost] for service [http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas] and principal [admin]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl]Publishing org.jasig.cas.support.events.CasServiceTicketGrantedEvent@4de8af38[ticketGrantingTicket=TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost,serviceTicket=ST-1-TI2dqfpSJIm9BTQs0tZE-localhost]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.TicketOrCredentialPrincipalResolver]Resolving argument [String] for audit
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]Ticket [TGT-**********************************************gw1L7hkf06-localhost] found in registry.
[INFO][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager]Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: admin
WHAT: ST-1-TI2dqfpSJIm9BTQs0tZE-localhost for http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sat Apr 29 14:02:49 CST 2017
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction]Warning cookie path is set to null and path /ucas/
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction]TGC cookie path is set to null and path /ucas/
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultArgumentExtractor]Created http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas based on org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.WebApplicationServiceFactory@7fec2fde
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultArgumentExtractor]Extractor generated service for: http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction]Placing service in context scope: [http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction]Placing registered service [^(https|http|imaps)://.*] with id [10000001] in context scope
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.GenerateLoginTicketAction]Generated login ticket LT-2-d4WAw9gubZB9FE6AzWx5-localhost
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction]Warning cookie path is set to null and path /ucas/
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction]TGC cookie path is set to null and path /ucas/
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultArgumentExtractor]Created http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas based on org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.WebApplicationServiceFactory@7fec2fde
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultArgumentExtractor]Extractor generated service for: http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction]Placing service in context scope: [http://localhost:8081/eadp_oa/shiro-cas]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction]Placing registered service [^(https|http|imaps)://.*] with id [10000001] in context scope
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.web.flow.GenerateLoginTicketAction]Generated login ticket LT-3-OOjFkWBQzVOWPtkCpPJN-localhost
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:03:42][org.jasig.cas.util.CasSpringBeanJobFactory]Created job org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl$ServiceRegistryReloaderJob@6bbdc5de for bundle org.quartz.spi.TriggerFiredBundle@52eb5693
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:03:42][org.jasig.cas.util.CasSpringBeanJobFactory]Autowired job per the application context
[INFO][2017-04-2914:03:42][org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl]Reloading registered services.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:03:42][org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl]Adding registered service ^(https|http|imaps)://.*
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:03:42][org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl]Adding registered service ^https://www.apereo.org
[INFO][2017-04-2914:03:42][org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl]Loaded 2 services from JsonServiceRegistryDao.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:03:48][org.jasig.cas.util.CasSpringBeanJobFactory]Created job org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry@3b2942e1 for bundle org.quartz.spi.TriggerFiredBundle@4e4cda28
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:03:48][org.jasig.cas.util.CasSpringBeanJobFactory]Autowired job per the application context
[INFO][2017-04-2914:03:48][org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[INFO][2017-04-2914:03:48][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]Beginning ticket cleanup...
[INFO][2017-04-2914:03:48][org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry]0 expired tickets found and removed.
```

shiro-cas client got xml analysis fail exception,because it got the html page content not xml

```
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHandler]Recording session for token ST-1-TI2dqfpSJIm9BTQs0tZE-localhost
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.client.session.HashMapBackedSessionMappingStorage]Attempting to remove Session=[5963FECCB62C5342CB3E599CF5BD6549]
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.client.session.HashMapBackedSessionMappingStorage]No mapping for session found.  Ignoring.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator]Placing URL parameters in map.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator]Calling template URL attribute map.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator]Loading custom parameters from configuration.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator]Constructing validation url: http://localhost:8080/ucas/serviceValidate?ticket=ST-1-TI2dqfpSJIm9BTQs0tZE-localhost&service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Feadp_oa%2Fshiro-cas
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:49][org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator]Retrieving response from server.
[DEBUG][2017-04-2914:02:50][org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator]Server response: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>CAS &#8211; Central Authentication Service</title>

    <meta name="_csrf" content=""/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content=""/>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ucas/css/cas.css" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/ucas/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  ...
```

i read cas protocal doc and search it,still couldn't understand why it happends,What i need to do more? Please advice me.

**solved**

i rollback all custom configuration and compare it,finally figure out what's happen.

i add these tx spring conf in cas server file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

it cause some final class cannot be initialize by spring, like:

```
org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory
org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl
```

so i override these final class, and it cause sso server cannot validate service ticket.
i remove this property:

```
proxy-target-class="true"
```

now sso server work.

Comment: Something isn't consistent here? `/cas/` in your message, `/ucas` in your logs, etc.

Comment: sorry about that typo,cas server context is /ucas